# having trouble with wrapper height

Tags: html, css

hi i am haveing trouble with height.. please tell me friends how can i resolve this issue.

[Please check here to check the website](http://www.ukash2gold.com/blog/rates/)

this is the link of my website. and Rates page .. i am having trouble with height.

i wrappered all the content in

```
#wrapper {
    background: url("images/wrapper_bg.png") repeat-y scroll left top transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 960px;
}
```

but

```
#main {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 960px;
}
```

is not responding for the internet height.

please help me

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=height+of+the+internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `overflow:auto;` in your `#main`

The main issue is the elements inside of `#main` are floated.  So the height of the floated elements won't cause the height of `#main` to expand

**OR**

put `clear:both;` on the `#footer`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that because everything inside your #main div has the float property set.  Basically, this makes main look like it has no elements, which causes the #footer div to rise up.  I can think of two ways to fix this:

1. Add "overflow: hidden" to your #main style, or
2. Add "clear: both" to your #footer style

Comment: thank you very much.. i tried 2nd way already but i was not going well .. but i tried first way as @Henesnarfel and you told me and its working fine.